# MYSQL join not bringing correct result

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner-join, outer-join

I have created the following query which includes 2 joins and is working fine:

```
SELECT a.name, b.tid
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b2.id, b2.status,  MAX(b2.created_time) as max_time
  FROM oac.qualys_scan b2
  GROUP BY b2.id  ,  b2.qualys_type
  ) t on t.id = a.id  
      AND  t.status=b.status
      AND t.max_time = b.created_time
WHERE b.status = 'FAIL';
```

The output is coming as follows:

```
id      tid     name
17695   19512   abc.com
17781   19628   abc1.com
17805   19732   abc2.com
17806   19703   abc3.com
17807   19704   abc4.com
```

I have another table table3 which has following values

```
id  tid     name                        details
842 19512   abc.com                     Details Description 1
843 19628   abc1.com                    Details Description 2
```

I want to join the above query with table3 on `tid` such that I get the following output

```
id      tid     name          details      
17695   19512   abc.com       Details Description 1
17781   19628   abc1.com      Details Description 1
```

I am using the following query but it is returning only one row which is not correct

```
SELECT a.name, b.tid
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b2.id, b2.status,  MAX(b2.created_time) as max_time
  FROM oac.qualys_scan b2
  GROUP BY b2.id  ,  b2.qualys_type
  ) t on t.id = a.id
      AND  t.status=b.status
      AND t.max_time = b.created_time
INNER JOIN table3 T3 on b.tid = T3.tid
WHERE b.status = 'FAIL'
```

Comment: if replace `inner join` with `left join table3 T3`, how many rows return?

Comment: Thanks for the input & output tables. However please read & act on [mcve] so that all necessary code can be cut & pasted & run--including DDL & input & output.

Answer (score 0):

Make your query a sub-query and join it to the table

```
    WITH BASELINE AS
    (
    SELECT a.name AS name, b.tid AS tid
    FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
         table2 b
         ON a.id = b.id
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT b2.id, b2.status,  MAX(b2.created_time) as max_time
      FROM oac.qualys_scan b2
      GROUP BY b2.id  ,  b2.qualys_type
      ) t on t.id = a.id  
          AND  t.status=b.status
          AND t.max_time = b.created_time
    WHERE b.status = 'FAIL';
    )
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    SELECT
     base.tid
     , base.name
     , t3.details

    FROM
     BASELINE base
    LEFT JOIN 
     Table3 t3
    ON base.tid = t3.tid
```

Is not the neatest solution but it always works for me